# Ejecutar evento al perder el foco

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

Tengo un Drop Down List, que quiero que ejecute el evento de perder foco, porque hasta recien estaba usando

> SelectedIndexChanged

Pero no necesito este en realidad, porque cada vez que se cambie el index del DDL va a ejecutar un evento y le va a pegar a la API (y deberia ser asi, el problema es que si el ddl tiene muchos items, y el usuario usa las flechas para buscar el item deseado, va a ejecutar el evento N veces y no quiero que pase eso) pero quiero que sea una unica vez y cuando pierda el focus en el DDL.

Estoy usando ASP.Net con WebForms, alguien me podria decir como usar el evento de perder el foco? El elemento ahora esta asi

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlLocalidad" AutoPostBack="true" OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlLocalidad_SelectedIndexChanged">
```

Y lo ejecuto asi

```
protected void ddlLocalidad_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Answer (score 1):

Debería ser posible usar el evento LostFocus

```
<asp:DropDownList runat="server" CssClass="form-control" ID="ddlLocalidad" AutoPostBack="true" OnLostFocus="ddlLocalidad_LostFocus">
```

llamando:

```
protected void ddlLocalidad_LostFocus(object sender, EventArgs e)
```

Por si te sirve de mas ayuda este artículo: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.lostfocus?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: Usa el evento focus  mediante el event listener

Comment: Andres, ya habia probado eso y no lo ejecuta al evento. No entiendo por que. Algo que hace es que si eligo otro item y no lo cambio mas pierde el foco despues de unos segundos el drop down list, pero sin saber por que hace eso.